# Remove IPEndpoint Bind

Tags: c#

I have a small form (FORM2) which acts like a pop up window. It takes an IPAddress as an argument and connects to it. The code below shows the connection

```
myNewUDP.newUDPClient = new UdpClient();
myNewUDP.newEP        = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), PORT);
IPEndPoint newBindEP  = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT);

//Set port to listen to
myNewUDP.newUDPClient.Client.Bind(newBindEP);
```

When I call the pop up for the first time it connects to the device correctly. However, during the subsequent calls it throws an exception "only one usage of each socket address is permitted ". How can I solve this issue ? Is there a way to close the IP and port binding ?

Answer (score 2):

*Connecting* would mean connecting to some other endpoint. Here you are *binding*, which means you reserve the protocol/port/ip for yourself. To remove the binding call `Close()` on the socket.

You are also using `UdpClient` a bit strangely since you are directly calling `Bind()` on the underlying socket. You could just use a plain `Socket` then. Or you can use the actual `UdpClient` to handle everything.

Comment: When I call my pop up the second time, the message is not being transmitted. Simply closing the UdpClient will solve this ?

Comment: I tried doing myNewUDP.newUDPClient.Close() during the form2 closing event, but still produces the same error.

Comment: @Abin And what about `myNewUDP.newUDPClient.Client.Close()` since you're poking at the underlying socket directly?

Comment: When I do that, I get another exception on my receive call back about resource not available.                   NewUdpState MynewUDP = (NewUdpState)ar.AsyncState;

            //Obtain udp msg
            ReceiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MynewUDP.newUDPClient.EndReceive (ar, ref MynewUDP.newEP));