# How to check if resource is available in c#

Tags: c#

This question is an extension of: [Remove IPEndpoint Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152235/remove-ipendpoint-bind)

I have closed the UDP client in form_closing event, but my receivecallback triggers after closing, raising the resource unavailable exception.
How can I check if my resource is available?

```
NewUdpState MynewUDP = (NewUdpState)ar.AsyncState; //Obtain udp msg      
ReceiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MynewUDP.newUDPClient.EndReceive (ar, ref MynewUDP.newEP));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check `MynewUDP.newUDPClient.Active`, if it's `false` you can simply return.

Comment: It shows "MynewUDP.newUDPClient.Active is inaccessible due to its protection level"